# Kubernetes: What pod uses most CPU on a node?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is there any way to list all PODs that are using the most CPU on the node using `kubectl` command. I could not see this in the official documentation.

Answer (score 6):

You can get by using

```
kubectl top pods    # This will give you which pod is using how much CPU and Memory

kubectl top nodes   # This will give you which node is using how much CPU and Memory
```

Make sure metric server has deployed on the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

To know which pod scheduled on a specific node has most CPU requests you can describe that node and check the `Non-terminated Pods` section.

```
kubectl describe node masternode

Non-terminated Pods:          (8 in total)
  Namespace                   Name                                        CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  AGE
  ---------                   ----                                        ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  kube-system                 calico-kube-controllers-76d4774d89-vmsnf    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         30d
  kube-system                 calico-node-t4qzr                           250m (12%)    0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         30d
  kube-system                 coredns-66bff467f8-v9mn5                    100m (5%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (1%)        170Mi (4%)     30d
  kube-system                 etcd-ip-10-0-0-38                           0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         30d
  kube-system                 kube-apiserver-ip-10-0-0-38                 250m (12%)    0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         30d
  kube-system                 kube-controller-manager-ip-10-0-0-38        200m (10%)    0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         30d
  kube-system                 kube-proxy-nf7jp                            0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         30d
  kube-system                 kube-scheduler-ip-10-0-0-38                 100m (5%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         30d
```

If the cluster have [metrics server](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server) deployed then below commands are useful to know pod and node CPU utilization

```
kubectl top podname
kubectl top nodename
```

Answer (score 1):

For nodes that have many pods across multiple namespaces I use an alias in .bash_profile.  Outputs the cpu and memory for all pods on given node.

```
kntp () {
  for p in `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --field-selector spec.nodeName=$1` | grep -v "Completed" | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $2}'`; do 
    kubectl top pod --all-namespaces --field-selector metadata.name=$p | tail -n +2
  done
}
```

Run it like

```
source ~/.bash_profile
kntp my-node-name-here
```

Answer (score 0):

You [can use](https://signoz.io/blog/kubectl-top/):

```
kubectl top pods --all-namespaces --sort-by=cpu
```

To find the CPU and memory usage of all the pods among all available namespaces.

The `CPU (cores)` is the CPU usage:

> 338m means 338 millicpu. 1000m is equal to 1 CPU, hence 338m means 33.8% of 1 CPU.